Understanding how these two expression from QFT are equivalent
I'm following Peskin & Schroeder's Intro to QFT, and in the chapter of the Dirac Equation, we derive the following expression after applying a boost to the plane wave solutions to the equation, $u(p_0)$:
$$u(p)=\left(\begin{matrix}
[\sqrt{E+p^3 }(\frac{1-\sigma^3}{2})+\sqrt{E-p^3 }(\frac{1+\sigma^3}{2})]\xi\\
[\sqrt{E+p^3 }(\frac{1+\sigma^3}{2})+\sqrt{E-p^3 }(\frac{1-\sigma^3}{2})]\xi
\end{matrix} \right)$$
I have been able to understand how we got to this point. However, then they say that "the last line can be simplified to give:
$$u(p)=\left(\begin{matrix}
\sqrt{p\cdot\sigma }\xi\\
\sqrt{p\cdot\bar{\sigma }}\xi
 \end{matrix}\right)$$
What I Tried: Since I didn't know how to go from the former to the latter, I tried working backwards. I know that taking the square root of a matrix means taking the positive root of each eigenvalue, so I could rewrite the second equation here as:
$$u(p)=\left(\begin{matrix}
\sqrt{p\cdot\sigma } & 0\\
0 &\sqrt{p\cdot\bar{\sigma }}
 \end{matrix}\right)\left(\begin{matrix} \xi \\ \xi \end{matrix}\right)$$
And since $p=(E,0,0,p^3)$ and $\sigma=(1,\sigma^i)$, I get that $$p\cdot \sigma =E+p^3 $$
Similarly, $$p\cdot\bar{\sigma}=E-p^3$$, which leaves me at:
$$u(p)=\left(\begin{matrix}
\sqrt{E+p^3 } & 0\\
0 &\sqrt{E-p^3}
 \end{matrix}\right)\left(\begin{matrix} \xi \\ \xi \end{matrix}\right)$$
Which is looking kind of like what I started with, but I don't know where the factos with the sigmas come in. I think they may be connected to the Left or right projection operators, which I believe were something like this:
$$P_L=(\frac{1-\sigma^3}{2})$$
$$P_R=(\frac{1+\sigma^3}{2})$$
And if I were to multiply a spinor with these components by what I have so far, I could get what I started with, but it feels incredibly forced and I don't know if it is even correct, and if it is, how it would even be justified.
So at this point, I am stuck, and would highly appreciate any help figuring this out

Can you please number the equations as in P&S' book?

You're almost there. All you now need to do is the express $P_L$ and $P_R$ as matrices to see that they select out the individual elements in the 2x2 matrix where the two previously obtained square roots are located. A key thing is that the simplified expression is also more general in that it does not only apply for the $z$-direction.

Notice that your equation
$$p\cdot \sigma =E+p^3 $$
is wrong, and is actually
$$p\cdot \sigma = \left(\begin{matrix}
E+p^3  & 0\\
0 & E-p^3
 \end{matrix}\right) = (E+p^3) P_L + (E - p^3) P_R,
$$
where I have used the projectors that you have defined. The rest follows.
